# Cannot sharing my second harddrive with Samba

Tags: server, partitioning, permissions, hard-drive, samba

I shared my first hdd in Ubuntu 16.04 with Samba and successful, but now I can't share my second hdd.

```
Windows cannot access \\192.168.1.99\server_2 
You do not have permission
```

I click [this](https://www.techwalla.com/articles/how-to-format-a-linux-disk) and I found nothing. And [another link](https://askubuntu.com/questions/545060/ubuntu-file-sharing-server-with-samba-using-external-hard-drive).

I tried to search and practice, but no results. It still cannot open. Even if I'm using Samba GUI.

I tried to change ownership and permission too. But it cannot open. It makes me confused.

I am still a noob at this, any help?

Answer (score 2):

A "Windows cannot access .... You do not have permissions" error is usually not a Samba issue but a Linux permissions issue. The folder that is shared and the path to that folder has to allow the samba client user access.

This type of problem usually results when a second HDD is partitioned and mounted to /media/your-user-name/XXX. The way Linux is set up the only user granted access to XXX is "your-user-name" regardless of the permissions of XXX itself.

There is an easy fix for this in a home network and that is to add a line in smb.conf that forces all remote users to appear to be "your-user-name" - at least for your samba shares:

```
force user = your-user-name
```

Where you put that line in smb.conf depends on how you created your samba share. If the share definition is in smb.conf then add the line to the share definition. If you are creating shares through the file manager then add it to the [global] section of smb.conf - right under the "workgroup = WORKGROUP" line is where I would put it.

If you want more specific guidance you need to edit your question and add the results of the following commands:

```
testparm -s

net usershare info --long
```